# Devexpress textbox ip mask for vuejs

Tags: devexpress, ip-address, maskedinput

I have a problem i want to use IP mask for devextreame text box, to have the possibility to use all valid IP addresses in the range of valid IP address 000.000.0.0 to 000.000.000.000, I'm trying to set mask rules with regexp, but it doesn't work as expected I can't for example use 192.168.1.1 I need always use 192.123.133.122 but I need possible range.

Here is my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/overview-devextreme-text-box-forked-nvqgsh?file=/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you with the code: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/TextBox/Specify_a_Mask_for_the_Input/

And this will be useful for the mask:
https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/cq41153/ip-address-mask